# PhoneGap for Android - Fragment containing PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, fragment

I want to have a FragmentActivity with 2 Fragments. One of them runs a DroidGap, and the other one runs a permanent camera. Is there a way for me to do this? This diagram below illustrates what I want:

```
FragmentActivity (
  Fragment 1: camera
  Fragment 2: DroidGap
)
```

DroidGap extends Activity. 
How do I run an existing Activity as a fragment? I tried startActivity() from Fragment.onActivityCreated(), but that simply calls the parent FragmentActivity.onActivityCreated(), which switches the entire Activity to the DroidGap. Is there an adapter that would treat an general Activity as a Fragment?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap v1.9 comes with CordovaWebView. This allows you to add PhoneGap into Fragments or ActivityGroup.

- See Wiki at: http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/CordovaWebView
- Working example: https://github.com/infil00p/CordovaActionView